# How to disable double encode in requests on redirects

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

I uses the jenkinsapi python scrips for downloading the artifacts generated by jenkins.
I used https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi and http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/
It didn't works after jenkins didn't allow double encode url

The problem:
Url somehow got double encode, and REST GET can't get the right result

example : 
query = tree=lastSuccessfuleBuild[number]

Good:
https://jenkins.developers.com/job/apk_builds/api/python?tree=lastSuccessfulBuild%5Bnumber%5D

Bad(righnow):
https://jenkins.developers.com/job/apk_builds/api/python?tree=lastSuccessfulBuild%255Bnumber%255D

can't return right results.
I check the requests. it happened on redirects and the code got double encode. I wonder if there is a way to disable the double encode on re-directs.

Update:

I google it and check some answers. it seem like requests package can't turn off encode on re-directs. The only walk around here is, instead of giving original URL, using the final (after re-directs URL). it should be fine. 
another possible options is allowed double encode on your Jenkins, which may cause security issues.

Comment: Hours wasted on trying to figure out why requests double-encodes my URL, not realizing that I have been redirected to a deceptively similar URL! Thanks for figuring this out.